# Why does pandas .sum(axis=1) return 0 when one row has numpy datetime64 values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with floating numbers in some rows and numpy datetime64 in another.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [[np.datetime64('2021-01-01'), np.datetime64('2021-01-01')], [2, 3]],
    columns=['A', 'B'])
```

when I sum each row (axis=1), I get 0 for all rows:

```
df2.sum(axis=1)

0    0.0
1    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Why does this happen? I have tried the numeric_only=True option with same result.

I would expect each row to be handled individually, and get 5 as result for the second row, as happens if I replace the datetime64 objects with strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': ['2021-01-01', 2],
     'B': ['2021-01-01', 3]})

print(df.sum(axis=1))

0    2021-01-012021-01-01
1                       5
dtype: object
```

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the sum of two dates?

Comment: I agree - does not make sense to add the dates, but that does not answer my question on why the dates interfere with the summation of another row

Answer (score 0):

You get get something like you're after if you make your rows columns

```
df2.transpose().sum(axis=0)
```

Your rows won't get coerced to a numerical dtype, i.e.

```
df2.loc[1]
```

results in

```
A    2
B    3
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Rows and columns are not treated equally in pandas, rightly or wrongly.